# Wordpress site gets infected with malware, random POST requests from hackers return 200 results, trying to understand how this happens

Tags: wordpress, http-post, malware

A word press site i maintain, gets infected with .ico extension PHP scripts and their invocation links. I periodically remove them. Now i have written a cron job to find and remove them every minute. I am trying to find the source of this hack. I have closed all the back doors as far as i know ( FTP, DB users etc..).

After reading similar questions and looking at https://perishablepress.com/protect-post-requests/, now i think this could be because of malware POST requests. Monitoring the access log i see plenty of POST requests that fail with 40X response. But i also see requests that succeed which should not. Example one below, first request fails, similar POST Requests succeeds with 200 response few hours later.

I tried duplicating a similar request from https://www.askapache.com/online-tools/http-headers-tool/, but that fails with 40X response. Help me understand this behavior. Thanks.

**POST Fails as expected**
146.185.253.165 - - [08/Dec/2019:04:49:13 -0700] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 403 134 "http://website.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) RockMelt/0.9.58.494 Chrome/11.0.696.71 Safari/534.24" website.com

**Few hours later same post succeeds** 
146.185.253.165 - - [08/Dec/2019:08:55:39 -0700] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 33827 "http://website.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_0) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.861.0 Safari/535.2" website.com

146.185.253.167 - - [08/Dec/2019:08:55:42 -0700] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 200 33827 "http://website.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1)

Comment: Install an antimalware plugin (eg. Wordfence, Sucuri, etc) and run a scan. It'll give you more info.

Comment: I had wordfence plugin (free version) installed. But it never prevented this issue. Will take a look at Sucuri.,